# equivalent of @Url.Content() in System.Web.WebPages.WebPage? (trying to get site base URL)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages

In an MVC site i would usually use `@Url.Content("~\")` to get my base URL. however, this method is not available in WebPages.

looking through `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpage(v=vs.111).aspx), i cant seem to find something equivalent, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [`Href`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpageexecutingbase.href(v=vs.111).aspx) method:

```
@Href("~/")
```